# Need advice on using xsl choose with contains and substring

Tags: xslt, xpath, substring, contains

I think I have this working but I need advice.  I'd like to know if this is a good setup for the requirement that I have.
I've got a requirement to apply different transformation rules to an element based on what is contained in that element.  I've tried to search for 'xsl' and 'choose', 'contains', 'substring'.  I can't seem to find a solution applicable to this situation.

Here are the various scenarios for this element:

1. If it begins with U, I need everything before the '/'

   - Original Value: UJXXXXX/001
   - Transformed   : UJXXXXX
2. If it begins with ECG_001 I need everything after ECG_001

   - Original Value: ECG_0012345678
   - Transformed   : 12345678
3. If it does not meet the above criteria and contains a '/' take everyting after the '/'

   - Original Value: F5M/12345678
   - Transformed   : 12345678
4. If it does not meet 1,2, or 3 just give me the value

   - Original Value : 12345678
   - Transformed    : 12345678

Here is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="CustomerPO">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(substring(rma/header/CustomerPO,1,1), 'U')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(rma/header/CustomerPO,'/')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(rma/header/CustomerPO, 'ECG_001')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(rma/header/CustomerPO,'ECG_001')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(rma/header/CustomerPO, '/')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(rma/header/CustomerPO, '/')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="rma/header/CustomerPO"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Any feedback on potential loopholes or a more efficient way to accomplish this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is good enough. I can't find nothing wrong on it, and I think there is no better solution. You could do it in a different way only if you used javascript or an external library, but I think it wouldn't improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT looks fine. You might consider using the `starts-with` function rather than `substring`, I find it easier to read, but I am not sure it is any faster.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for.  I was trying to find a begins-with function.  Not sure how I missed starts-with.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My own style would be to use template rules.

```
<xsl:template match="CustomerPO[starts-with(., 'U')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomerPO[starts-with(., 'ECG_001')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'ECG_001')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

etc.